# Possible to extract Embedded image to a file?

Tags: image, reporting-services

Given a SSRS report definition file with an embedded image in it, just wondering if its possible to extract that image XML to recreate the original image file.

e.g. :

inside the rdlc file, you might see xml like this :

```
<EmbeddedImage Name="tick">
  <MIMEType>image/bmp</MIMEType>
  <ImageData>Qk1mAwAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAEAAAABEAAAABABgA ... <<REST OF IMAGE HERE>>
  </ImageData>
</EmbeddedImage>
```

Is it possible to take the ImageData, and transform form it in some way to re-create the original image bitmap byte stream ?

(This might be useful in cases such as when you've lost the original image file on which the embedded image was based.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two approaches are detailed in [this blog post](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/65/posts/11587/extracting-images-from-ssrs-reports.aspx):

1. Copy the encoded image from one report to another if you need to reuse it there.
2. Export a copy of the report to Excel and copy the image from the spreadsheet.

Or if you need access to the image more directly, I found [this utility](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/07/22/extracting-embedded-images-from-ssrs-reports.aspx) that will parse the XML and load and export the images. Looks like source code is available.

Comment: thanks, the utility works well. A slight change was required to make it also work for rdlc files (including the *.rdlc filespec in the file open dialog).

Comment: Utility worked perfect for me. Only needed to change the open file dialog filter to "(*.rdl)|*.rdl|(*.rdlc)|*.rdlc", to allow opening rdlc files.

Answer (score 11):

I have created a small Power Shell script to solve this problem:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.rdl' | ForEach {
    $reportFile = $_;
    Write-Host $reportFile;
    $report = [xml](Get-Content $reportFile);
    $report.Report.EmbeddedImages.EmbeddedImage | Foreach {
        $imagexml = $_;
        $imageextension = $imagexml.MIMEType.Split('/')[1];
        $filename = $imagexml.Name + '.' + $imageextension;
        Write-Host '->' $filename;
        $imageContent =  [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($imagexml.ImageData);
        Set-Content -Path $filename -Encoding Byte -Value $imageContent;
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/Fabian-Schmidt/71746e8e1dbdf9db9278

This script extracts all images from all reports in the current folder.

Comment: Great script, thanks!
If you have multiple reports containing images with the same name but different content (e.g. "Header.png"), you can prefix the source report name to the image name by changing line 9 to
`$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($reportFile) + '.' + $imagexml.Name + '.' + $imageextension;`

Answer (score 7):

1. Open the XML (in notepad++ or anything)
2. Look for the `<ImageData></ImageData>` tags
3. Copy the 64-bit encoded string between the tags
4. Find a utility to convert x64 encoded strings to files. I used [this website](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and downloaded the image

Comment: This site is better https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder. I was unable to extract the image using your suggested site.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do this and realised that it is possible to cut and paste the embedded image, even though it is not possible to copy and paste.