# VS 2010, Getting embedded Image from rdlc report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, rdlc

I designed a rdlc report. In that I embedded one image, say logo. 
But I accidently deleted the orginal image in orginal location.
Now I am trying to resave the Logo from rdlc report.

In which location this rdlc's embedded image is getting stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is not stored in a physical location but in the rdl file itself. If you open the rdl file, you would find tag . It has been mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

There are a few ways of saving the image. It has already been answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004653/possible-to-extract-embedded-image-to-a-file) question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the danger of just posting links -- your link to M$ is now defunct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question.
The embedded images are stored as Base64 strings in rdlc. when you try to insert a new image in your report you have a dropdown of those images right under "use this image" or you can insert it from code